# Generating an arithmetic sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sequence

I would like to generate a named table in a `WITH` clause which will contain this arithmetic progression:

```
╔══════════╗
║ mynumber ║
╠══════════╣
║        0 ║
║       30 ║
║       60 ║
║       90 ║
║      120 ║
║      150 ║
║      180 ║
║      210 ║
╚══════════╝
```

...based on variable `p_maxnumber` (here `p_maxnumber` = 211 for example).

Ideally it would be in a format like:

```
WITH sequenceTable AS
(SELECT mynumber
FROM ...),
```

Within the same `WITH` clause, I would like to use that sequence in downstream derived tables to get data and to be eventually used as a time axis for chart rendering.  I have a feeling there is a way to do it using create sequence?  Just trying to figure a way to create this still...

Comment: Check this link: http://hashfactor.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/sql-generating-series-of-numbers-in-oracle/

Comment: interesting idea... would definitely work, though I think I preferred Vincent's answer for this one, thanks.

Comment: @SQL Kiwi FYI, this is almost never useful in Oracle.  A CONNECT BY query as shown below can generate rows faster and with less overhead.  Such a table may be useful on other databases and can be useful in Oracle in unusual scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a CONNECT BY query to generate an arbitrary sequence:

```
SQL> variable v_step NUMBER
SQL> variable v_maxnumber NUMBER
SQL> exec :v_step := 30; :v_maxnumber := 211;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> WITH sequenceTable AS (
  2     SELECT (LEVEL - 1) * :v_step myNumber
  3       FROM DUAL
  4     CONNECT BY (LEVEL - 1) * :v_step <= :v_maxnumber)
  5  SELECT * FROM sequenceTable;

  MYNUMBER
----------
         0
        30
        60
        90
       120
       150
       180
       210

8 rows selected
```

You can also use a pipelined function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_number IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  2  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arithmetic_sequence (p_step NUMBER, p_maxvalue NUMBER)
  2     RETURN tab_number
  3     PIPELINED
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR i IN 0..p_maxvalue/p_step LOOP
  7        PIPE ROW (i*p_step);
  8     END LOOP;
  9     RETURN;
 10  END;
 11  /

Function created

SQL> SELECT COLUMN_VALUE myNumber FROM TABLE(arithmetic_sequence(30, 211));

  MYNUMBER
----------
         0
        30
        60
        90
       120
       150
       180
       210

8 rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks, the CONNECT BY was exactly what I was trying to find.